# validation for 'dispaly:none' field in angular

Tags: angular

I am using Template driven form in angular. from the given form when I select member id and enter data in the input field and then select checkbox then my button is not enabled.
when I select membrId then my date input field is `display:none` and when I select the date field becomes `display:block` and the member id remains `display:none`.

Please guide me, When I select `memberId` or date from the dropdown then put the data in the input field and select the checkbox then my button should be enabled.

component.html

```
<form #healthForm="ngForm" name="healthForm" (ngSubmit)="registerHealthPolicy(healthForm.value,healthForm.valid)">
    <select id="healthDropdown" class="select-policy select-policy-dropdown">
        <option value="memberID">Member ID</option>
        <option value="DOB">Date of Birth of Proposer</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <div class="member-id">
        <input class="input-box" oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" maxlength="20" type="number" name="healthMemberId" placeholder="Member ID" [(ngModel)]="healthMemberId"/>
    </div>
    <div class="date-box">
        <div class="date-container">
            <input class="input-box" autocomplete="false" type="text" name="healthDate" id="datepicker" placeholder="" [(ngModel)]="healthDate" required/>
            <span>
                <img src="assets/images/calendar.png">
            </span> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="terms-container">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1-2" name="health_terms" #healthTerms="ngModel" ngModel class="regular-checkbox" required/>
        <label for="checkbox-1-2"></label>
        <span>I have read the <a href="#" disabled data-toggle="modal" data-target="#terms_condition_modal_kgi" class="condition">Terms and Conditions</a> and agree to abide by the same.</span>
        <br/>
        <small class="validation-error" [hidden]="healthTerms.valid || (healthTerms.pristine && !healthForm.submitted)">Please accept terms and conditions</small>                                            
    </div>
    <button class="sbmt-btn" type="submit" [disabled]="!healthForm.valid || !healthTerms">Submit</button>
</form>
```

component.ts

```
ngOnInit(){
   $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
        maxDate: "-1m",
        yearRange: "1940:c"
    });
}
```

component.css

```
select.select-policy-dropdown::-ms-expand,
select.select-policy::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
}

.date-box {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Please help us.

Comment: Why not to use `*ngIf` or `[ngClass]`?